# Разработка иерархии классов геометрических фигур

Tags: c++

Нужно разработать иерархию классов пространственные фигуры: конус, паралепипед, куб, сфера, эллипсоид, цилиндр. Как это лучше организовать, там, какой клас брать за базовый и тп ?

Comment: ООП

прямоугольные от квадрата

эллипсоиды от круга

треугольники от.. короче, кэп устал =)

Comment: Очень плохой ответ. Отношение наследования по сути есть отношение "является". Поэтому прямоугольник от квадрата наследовать не стоит.

Comment: А что Вы собираетесь делать с объектами Ваших классов? Как говорят в деревне, это зависит.

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/123014/  
ознакомтись, весьма полезно

Comment: квадрат как частная форма прямоугольника, я имел ввиду выделить основные типы фигур и от них наследовать походные. Посмотрел ссылку(та что в комментарии под вопросом), имхо, тут же очевидно, что круг - частный случай эллипса, т.е. эллипс с одинаковым радиусом. А выделять интерфейс "тело" - это неправильный уровень абстракции, так можно и точку брать, че уж там.... а если и брать - так пусть хоть тип и имя хранит =)

Comment: Прямоугольник от квадрата и в самом деле не стоит. А наоборот можно (квадрат частный случай прямоугольника, а  шар это частный случай эллипсоида), но зачем ?  

В данном вопросе объемные фигуры можно наследовать от тех плоских, для которых они являются телами вращения. Цилиндр от прямоугольника, эллипсоид от эллипса, конус от треугольника и т.п.

Только вот без понимания множества задач, для которых все это требуется подобная разработка дело пустое.

Comment: @avp, в общем ты все правильно подытожил =)млин, до меня ток что дошло, извеняюсь, я не правильно озвучил идею, но и я не мог сразу понять, что так буквально понимаются слова "Прямоугольник от квадрата и в самом деле не стоит", мы же не говорим про статические фигуры, тут то и смысла нету. Какая разница кого от кого наследовать, если по сути это тот же объект только с разными значениями высоты, ширины и длинны. Я ввел к наследию от схожих по свойствам фигур

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом верху иерархии абстрактный класс допустим `Figure` с набором виртуальных функций для работы с объектами ну типа нарисовать и проч.

На втором уровне фигуры с одним параметром: куб (сторона) и сфера (радиус)

На третьем уровне фигуры с 2-мя параметрами с наследованием от 1-параметрических фигур, например эллипсоид, цилиндр и конус наследуется от сферы, параллепипед от куба и т.д.

Comment: Обычно удобней наоборот - из общего (параллепипед) делать частное (куб). 

Кстати, не нарисуете, как из сферы получить конус ?

Comment: Здесь не вопрос удобства, а вопрос членов класса. Сфера имеет 1-го мембера = protected radius, а конус 2-х мемберов: radius и height, причем radius наследуется из сферы. Экономия места налицо. Нет?

Comment: Ну, если целью проектирования иерерхии классов считать экономию памяти под данные, то Да !

Answer (score 3):

Геометрические объекты - это один из особых случаев. Возьмем набор плоских фигур: Квадрат - Прямоугольник - Параллелограмм - Ромб

1. В геометрии квадрат - частный случай прямоугольника и ромба, прямоугольник - частный случай параллелограмма, ромб - частный случай параллелограмма.
   Такую цепочку мы не сможем реализовать т.к. в ООП наследование расширяющее, т.е. мы можем что-то добавить в наследника но не можем вырезать лишнее.
2. В ООП (расширяем функционал). Параллелограмм наследуется от ромба или прямоугольника, ромб наследуется от квадрата, прямоугольник наследуется от квадрата. Т.к. экземпляр производного класса также является экземпляром базового класса, то в данном контексте мы получаем, например, такое утверждение: любой прямоугольник - квадрат. А это противоречит геометрическому определению (да и логике).

С объемными фигурами, линиями поверхностями и т.д. ровно тоже самое.

Таким образом, мы можем выделить в качестве базового класса геометрических объектов абстрактный класс/интерфейс, например, GeometricSolid и определить в набор общих методов для вычисления объема и площади поверхности, это есть у всех фигур. Сами же фигуры унаследовать от данного класса/интерфейса, **все на одном уровне**. Только в таком виде ваша модель не будет противоречить ни ООП, ни геометрии.

Answer (score 0):

За базу можно выделить интерфейс "`Тело`". Интерфейсы в `C++` — это абстрактные классы.

Например, если это классы для системы визуализации, то имеет смысл объявить метод `draw` (нарисовать):

```
class body
{
    ...
    virtual void draw() = 0;    
    ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Вот тебе мой вариант решения, правда под себя. Бери переделывай для себя

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

using namespace std;

/*================================================
Создать иерархию классов Точка-Круг-Конус. Конус должен
содержать метод определения объема. Последние два класса
должны иметь конструкторы.
===================================================*/

class Point { //Класс Point
 public:
 int x;
 int y;
};

class Circle : public Point {
 public:
 float r1; //радиус круга

 Circle(float r1) {
 r1 = r1;
 }
};

class Cone : public Circle {
 public:
 double H;
 double volume;

 Cone(double r1, double h1):Circle(r1) {

 H = h1;
 }

 void calculate_volume() {

 volume = (1.0 / 3.0) * H * M_PI; //Формула для нахождения объема конуса
 }

};

/*================================================
Создать метод MAIN, в котором создается два конуса,
определяется какой из конусов меньше, а также входит 
ли меньший конус в больший. Также показать все 
характеристики создаваемых объектов.
===================================================*/

void main()
{

 setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); //настраиваем локаль
 setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

 /*================================================
 Такие параметры, чтобы меньший конус полностью
 входил в больший
 ===================================================*/
 Cone m(5, 6); //больший конус
 Cone n(5, 6); //меньший конус

 /*================================================
 Такие параметры, чтобы меньший конус не входил в 
 больший
 ===================================================*/
 //Cone m(4, 6); //больший конус
 //Cone n(6, 4); //меньший конус

 m.calculate_volume(); //считаем объем первого конуса
 n.calculate_volume(); //считаем объем второго конуса

 cout « "Объем первого конуса равен: " « m.volume « " кубических единиц" « endl;
 cout « "Объем второго конуса равен: " « n.volume « " кубических единиц" « endl;

 cout « "-------------------------------------------" « endl;

 //проверка, если объемы конусов разные
 if (m.volume > n.volume) {
 cout « "Меньший конус полностью входит в больший конус..." « endl;

 }
 else if (m.volume = n.volume) {
 cout « "Объемы двух конусов равны" « endl;;
 }
 else {
 cout « "Меньший конус не входит в большой конус..." « endl;
 }

 cout « "--------------------------------------------" « endl;
 cout « "Выводим все характеристики созданных объектов на экран: " « endl;
 cout « setw(25) « "Радиус первого конуса: " « m.r1 « setprecision(6) « endl;
 cout « setw(25) « "Высота первого конуса: " « m.H « endl;
 cout « setw(25) « "Радиус второго конуса: " « n.r1 « setprecision(6) « endl;
 cout « setw(25) « "Высота второго конуса: " « n.H « endl;

 system("pause");
}
```